# How to get the SID and User Name of the user utilising my service in C++

Tags: c++, windows, winapi

I am attempting to create a service that will essentially act as a local web server.  In theory users will use a REST API by visiting URIs through localhost in a browser i.e. http://localhost:2017/path/to/function/call will connect to the service and execute a function.

My question is how do I get the SID and User Name of the account that called the service?

I have implemented a couple of solutions but they return the SID and User Name of the service and not the user using it.

```
OJSon* UnifiedStreamingService::getUserDetails()
{

    OJSon* result = OJSon::create();
    if(result)
    {
        /*
        HANDLE hToken = NULL;
        ULONG id = WTSGetActiveConsoleSessionId();

        BOOL bRet = WTSQueryUserToken(id, &hToken);
        if (bRet == false)
        {
            DWORD error = GetLastError();
            printf("ERROR: %d", error);
        }
        */
        HANDLE hToken = NULL;
        if ( ! OpenProcessToken( GetCurrentProcess(), TOKEN_QUERY, &hToken ) ) 
        {
            //_tprintf( _T("OpenProcessToken failed. GetLastError returned: %d\n"), GetLastError());
            return NULL;
        }

        // Get the size of the memory buffer needed for the SID
        DWORD dwBufferSize = 0;
        if ( ! GetTokenInformation( hToken, TokenUser, NULL, 0, &dwBufferSize ) && ( GetLastError() != ERROR_INSUFFICIENT_BUFFER ) )
        {
            //_tprintf( _T("GetTokenInformation failed. GetLastError returned: %d\n"), GetLastError());
            // Cleanup
            CloseHandle( hToken );
            hToken = NULL;

            return NULL;
        }
        // Allocate buffer for user token data
        std::vector<BYTE> buffer;
        buffer.resize( dwBufferSize );
        PTOKEN_USER pTokenUser = reinterpret_cast<PTOKEN_USER>( &buffer[0] );
        // Retrieve the token information in a TOKEN_USER structure
        if ( ! GetTokenInformation( 
                 hToken, 
                 TokenUser, 
                 pTokenUser, 
                 dwBufferSize,
                 &dwBufferSize)) 
        {
            //_tprintf( _T("2 GetTokenInformation failed. GetLastError returned: %d\n"), GetLastError());
            // Cleanup
            CloseHandle( hToken );
            hToken = NULL;

            return NULL;
        }
        // Check if SID is valid
        if ( ! IsValidSid( pTokenUser->User.Sid ) ) 
        {
            //_tprintf( _T("The owner SID is invalid.\n") );
            // Cleanup
            CloseHandle(hToken);
            hToken = NULL;

            return NULL;
        }
        // add the name
        OString* name = lookupAccountSid(pTokenUser->User.Sid);
        if(name)
        {
            result->setKey(&OString("name"), name);
            SAFEDELETE(name);
        }
        // add the SID
        OString* sid = convertSidToString(pTokenUser->User.Sid);
        if(sid)
        {
            result->setKey(&OString("SID"), sid);
            SAFEDELETE(sid);
        }
        // Cleanup
        CloseHandle(hToken);
        hToken = NULL;

    }
    return result;
}

OString* UnifiedStreamingService::convertSidToString(PSID pSID)
{
    OString* result = NULL;

    if(pSID)
    {
        // Get string corresponding to SID
        LPTSTR pszSID = NULL;
        if ( ! ConvertSidToStringSid( pSID, &pszSID ) )
        {
            return NULL;
        }
        result = new OString(pszSID);
        // Release buffer allocated by ConvertSidToStringSid API
        LocalFree( pszSID );
        pszSID = NULL;
    }

    return result;
}

OString* UnifiedStreamingService::lookupAccountSid(PSID pSID)
{
DWORD dwSize = 256;
DWORD dwResult = 0;
SID_NAME_USE SidType;
LPTSTR lpName = new TCHAR[dwSize];
LPWSTR lpDomain = new TCHAR[dwSize];
OString* result = NULL;

    if( !LookupAccountSid( NULL, pSID, lpName, &dwSize, lpDomain, &dwSize, &SidType ) ) 
    {
        dwResult = GetLastError();
        return NULL;
    }

    OString* pDomain = new OString(lpDomain);
    OString* pName = new OString(lpName);
    if(pDomain && pName)
    {
        result = OString::createByFormat(&OString("%s\\%s"), pDomain, pName);

        SAFEDELETE(pDomain);
        SAFEDELETE(pName);
    }

    delete[] lpDomain;
    delete[] lpName;

    return result;
}
```

Comment: TCP/IP is anonymous, you will need to implement authentication in your server ie, prompt for a username and password.

Comment: Not sure about the exact conditions but if you need SID of the only logged-on user you could use WTSGetActiveConsoleSessionId and WTSQueryUserToken to get user token and then get SID with GetTokenInformation. But you need appropriate access rights to do this.

Comment: @KonstantinL I did try this technique but it resulted in the SID and User Name of the service.  Do you know what access right are required to make it return the user's SID and/or User Name?

Comment: Hmm.. something is wrong. In case of insufficient rights you should get Zero Handle, not service handle. Could you show your code?

Comment: @KonstantinL Hi, I have attached my current code.

Comment: and this code is executed without error messages?

Comment: Generally you get sessionId ('id' in your code) == 1. Is this so?

Comment: And what does the task manager show for sessionId for your client app and for service app?

Comment: Sorry I am actively trying to resolve this issue so the code is in flux and I provided code that did not work.  Using WTSGetActiveConsoleSessionId() I get a result of 1 which when passed to WTSQueryUserToken(id, &hToken) gives a result 0. GetLastError() then returns 1314 which I believe is insufficient privilege.  The edited code above results in the services SID and User Name being supplied.

Comment: I do not currently have a client app I am tust testing responses through the browser atm.  When running the the service the Task Manager shows the following details Name: UnifiedStreamingServiced.exe PID: 6716 Status: Running User Name: :LOCAL SERVICE CPU: 00 Memory: 1,664k, Description: Unified Streaming Service

Comment: @KonstantinL So it turns out my issue is the account the service was logging in as.  When logging in as a Local Service it didn't have sufficient privileges and was failing but when logging in as Local System it works and I am getting the information I am after.  If you post an answer I will mark it as accepted.  Thanks for your help, much appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The task can be accomplished by using WTSGetActiveConsoleSessionId and WTSQueryUserToken to get user token and then getting SID with GetTokenInformation.
The additional requirement is the service is running under Local System account which grants SE_TCB_NAME privelege (== SeTcbPrivilege). SE_TCB_NAME required by [WTSQueryUserToken](https://msdn.microsoft.com/query/dev14.query?appId=Dev14IDEF1&l=EN-US&k=k(WTSQueryUserToken);k(DevLang-C%2B%2B);k(TargetOS-Windows)&rd=true). Note that the other accounts usually have no SE_TCB_NAME privelege!

Comment: Ok, OP explicitely said that users would use a `localhost` URL so this answer can be acceptable. But you should at least warn that you are giving the URL **of the current session if any on the machine where the service run**. So it will not give expected result if clientA from machineA connects to a service of machineB runned by userB (you would get userB). Nor if a scheduled task running under userC on machineB connect to the service on machineB: still get userB

Comment: This approach doesn't account for: 1) the server machine having multiple users logged in at the same time, 2) no users logged in at all (services do not require users to be logged in), or 3) the machine being logged in to remotely. Rather than using `WTSGetActiveConsoleSessionId()`, consider using `WTSEnumerateSessions()` instead, looking for sessions in the `WTSActive` state (user logged in).

Comment: @RemyLebeau These are additional scenarios that I need to account for so I attempted to use the method you suggested however consequently LookUpAccountSid fails with error code 87 (ERROR_INVALID_PARAMETER) and ConvertSidToStringSid fails with error code 1337 (ERROR_INVALID_SID_STRUCTURE). Do you have any idea what may cause this?